# Emails very delayed getting from mandrill to gmail

Tags: email, gmail, mandrill

For the past 4 months we have been seeing large delays when sending emails through mandrill to gmail addresses. Sometimes it takes 15 minutes but other times it can be up to an hour. When i check the mandrill outbound section shortly after the email is sent it shows the email was delivered, but it usually takes a while before it actually shows up in my inbox. We are using this service for welcome emails and password resets so waiting long periods of time isn't acceptable.

It has been very hard to find any information on this issue. Has anyone seen this issue? Any recommendations on what i could do to fix it?

Comment: I also forgot to add that we have an excellent reputation with mandrill

Comment: Hmm, this is very puzzling. Are you experiencing similar issues with non-gmail providers? Have you configured a custom domain to send through Mandrill?

Comment: No we are just using the standard mandrill domain for sending the emails. We have just noticed the delays with gmail so far.

Comment: I'd suggest whitelabelling a custom domain - it's possible gmail is throttling the standard mandrill domain.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had similar issues with delays on emails sent via Mandrill to gmail.

To fix the issue I viewed the "Sending Domains" page under "Settings" in Mandrill. I discovered the DKIM and SPF DNS records were either missing or not valid.  Mandrill will provide you with new values by clicking on the "View... settings" link.  After updating these settings we no longer experience the delay.

Comment: Did it take a little bit for you to notice the different? I made the changes you suggested yesterday and we are still seeing large delays in the delivery of our emails

Comment: We noticed the changes immediately. Did you retest the settings and ensure they were valid?

Comment: I must say I still experience the issue even though all settings are correct in the 'Sending Domains' page.  I have three green check marks, yet e-mails sent to gmail or hotmail accounts can take a very long time to get delivered.

Comment: Jeff/bmunslow, what did you end up doing?  I'm seeing the same thing, emails take forever.  I just started with Mandrill but wondering if its temporary.  I'm paying and have the spf/dkim/domain all checked.

Answer (score 5):

I've run into this issue a number of times. Our DNS settings were all good (DKIM and SPF confirmed my Mandrill) and after some investigation (looking at the headers of the delayed emails) the delay appeared to be entirely on Mandrill's side (once it was handed off to Gmail or Yahoo the delivery occurred within a second). When I contact Mandrill support they explained why we were seeing these delays:

> In looking over the logs for your account we are seeing intermittent
>   delays for some of your recipients. Generally, the speed of delivery
>   in most cases depends largely on the receiving domain, and how quickly
>   they will receive and process emails. Most of the major email
>   providers limit how much email they'll receive in a certain period of
>   time, and will restrict delivery—Mandrill's sending servers are
>   designed to queue and back off sending if this occurs. In these cases,
>   the receiving mail server or ISP will return a specific kind of SMTP
>   response telling Mandrill's servers to 'back off' and 'try again
>   later,' which ultimately results in the message lingering on our mail
>   servers longer than expected (and since the message isn't passed off
>   to the receiving server at that point, and we're only getting a 'try
>   again' response, you won't see that information in the message headers
>   of the final email you receive. You'll only see that the email stayed
>   on our servers for a longer time period which can be confusing).
>
> Additionally, even though we may hand the messages off to ISPs for
>   delivery almost immediately, it's still up to that ISP, like Gmail or
>   Yahoo, to actually to process that email and place it in the inbox.
>   Each receiving server is different though, so it may take a different
>   amount of time for Yahoo to process the mail than Gmail, for example.
>   In many cases, things like the time of day and overall email traffic
>   to that recipient server can affect how quickly they're able to
>   receive and process email.
>
> All that said, the delays you're seeing generally aren't expected, and
>   while we see that messages are ultimately delivering, we are detecting
>   factors on our end where we may need to make some changes to help
>   mitigate further delays. Our delivery team is continuing to monitor
>   traffic to major ISPs and will make necessary adjustments as needed.

We still periodically see these delays, though they've improved is so the delays are rarely longer than 10 minutes or so, but it still can cause issues with things like password resets or confirmations that are time-sensitive. Bottom line: Mandrill is awesome for bulk mailing, but if you need instantaneous delivery you may want to rely on a different or self-hosted service.

Comment: I'd love to know if there are any transactional email providers that *don't* regularly have these delays.  We use Sailthru, and see them intermittently as well.  Not *that* often, but often enough that it's a fairly serious customer service issue.

Answer (score 2):

I also had gmail showing emails sent through mandrill around 10 minutes later. And that is unacceptable to register confirmations and password resets.

I had configured my DKIM and SPF dns records and mandrill reported all green in this records.

But mail delivery to gmail was always delayed with no aparent reason.

After a while **I decided do test/use my own email server** to do this, instead of mandrill. Now there are no delays in gmail. I'm happy :)

After this I think I will only use mandrill for massive email delivery / marketing, where delays are not important. Time will tell.

Would like to hear other people about this subject.

Answer (score 1):

In **mandrillapp.com > Settings > Domains > Sending domains**, verify these 3 points:

- DKIM is valid,
- SPF is valid,
- domain is verified.

Answer (score 1):

My experience has been that the Google SMTP servers are causing the delay (not Mandrill). Verify this by looking at the original email headers (in gmail, with email opened, in the top right More > Show Original) and pasting the email header into the google [Message header analyzer](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/messageheader/) will show you the path your email took and how long it was delayed at each server. This report will also tell you if you DKIM / SPF is invalid.

Why the delay is occurring is still a mystery to me. I suspect however that because the domain I am using to send is new, perhaps the gmail spam filters are grey listing the emails until enough users have opened emails and not clicked the spam button? I don't know.