# Mandrill: Why is Gmail so slow?

Tags: gmail, mailchimp, mandrill

I'm using mandrill to send out activation links for an account a user just set up. For every mail provider except gmail, the email pops up instantly on the users email. What's up with gmail? Is there any workaround I can do to pick up the delivery speed? It's taking 15-30 minutes to deliver.

Comment: Same here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926024/emails-very-delayed-getting-from-mandrill-to-gmail