# Sending Gmail through Mandrill - Emails are delayed

Tags: time, smtp, gmail, delay, mandrill

1. Checked many solutions over the web including this : 
   [Emails very delayed getting from mandrill to gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926024/emails-very-delayed-getting-from-mandrill-to-gmail)
2. In mandrillapp.com > Settings > Domains > Sending domains, verify these 3 points:

DKIM is valid,
SPF is valid,
domain is verified.

3. We have noticed that those delay usually occurs after let's say a day / few hours of email sending inactivity (meaning : We are not sending any emails through mandrill during that time).
4. As We need massive Emails in very HIGH volume We have a real problem here.
5. We like very much the mandrill interface, Thus, If solution / workaround (not ugly like sending dummy email through a scheduled task /job or something) exits, We prefer it, rather than moving to another paid service.

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the Google SMTP servers are causing the delay, this was my experience. In gmail, open the email that was delayed and in the top right select More > Show Original) and copy and paste the email header into the [google Message header analyzer](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/messageheader/). This will show you the path your email took and how long it was delayed at each server. My research as to why gmail caused delay has turned up nil, even though many people are experiencing the problem. I suspect it's because the emails are being put on the grey list queue in gmail.